# Erro ao iniciar o projeto com zend Framework

Tags: zend

Segui o passo a passo do tutorial do zend porem não ta funcionando quando tento inicializar o projeto pelo netbeans.Sou novo ai recem formado galera quem puder por favor ajuda ai.Valeu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Na pasta de instação do Apache, acha o arquivo httpd.conf (ou httpd-vhosts.conf em alguns sistemas) e inclui esse bloco:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName quickstart.local
DocumentRoot /path/to/quickstart/public

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory /path/to/quickstart/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Aí você substitui o caminho do DocumentRoot pelo caminho até onde tá a pasta public na sua aplicação.

Aqui tem um ótimo tutorial para começar: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: eu nao entendi o que você quis dizer com isso -> ServerName quickstart.local DocumentRoot /path/to/quickstart/public

Comment: Olha a parte de "Create a virtual host" do link que te passei. Aqui ele tá cortando o código, por isso tá estranho

Comment: ta dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Como tá seu /public/index.php?

Comment: colei ai a imagem, eu nao alterei nada nele @FabioNader

Comment: eu to perdido cara só quero começar um projeto com php sou desenvolvedor iniciante e recem formado @FabioNader

Comment: Pelo seu print parece que a pasta library está vazia... Certeza que o Zend tá lá?

Comment: sim está você tem facebook?

Comment: Tenho sim... To como Fabionader